# Как перевести на русский проект на Django?

Tags: локализация, django

Как перевести на русский проект на Django?

Answer (score 2):

Установить [django-rosetta](http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/) и переводить через web-интерфейс.

Answer (score 1):

1. Убедиться, что модуль gettext установлен.
2. Взять нужный .po файл и перевести все строки.
3. Скомпилировать .po файл командой `django-admin.py compilemessages --locale=ru_RU` (или подобной).